# Error of prediction from the required line of regression

Tags: statistics, correlation, linear-regression

> The error of prediction of x from the required line of regression is $n\sigma^2_x(1-\rho^2)$

This is given in my reference without any further explanation. What does this realy mean and how do we arrive such a conclusion ?

**Things I know**
$$
\rho=\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_x.\sigma_y}\\
$$

The regression line of $y$ on $x$ is $y-\bar{y}=\rho\dfrac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}(x-\bar{x})=b_{yx}(x-\bar{x})$ and The regression line of $x$ on $y$ is $x-\bar{x}=\rho\dfrac{\sigma_x}{\sigma_y}(y-\bar{y})=b_{xy}(y-\bar{y})$
$$
\rho^2=b_{yx}.b_{xy}
$$
And I understand the regression line is derived by minimizing $s=\sum\epsilon^2=\sum\Big[(ax+b)-y\Big]^2$

Comment: Have you quoted the statement correctly?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks for mentioning. I have edited the equation

Comment: I would guess the error of prediction of $x$ from the regression line of $x$ on $y$ is the residual variance given by $\sigma_x^2(1-\rho^2)$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I am looking for a derivation of the given formula. Could you please guide me ?

Comment: I don't understand the given formula. I think it is supposed to be the residual variance given by $Var(x-\hat x)$ where $x=a+by+\varepsilon$ is your prediction model and $\hat x=\hat a+\hat by$ is your least squares predictor.